# create an instance of a manager class

Tags: c#

Let's say I have a class CustomerManager with a lot of methods that interact with the DAL.CustomerManager. But there are also lot's of mehods that not interact with the DAL.CustomerManager class.

Should I instantiate the _dalCustomerManager class like the code below?

```
public class CustomerManager {

    private DAL.CustomerManager _dalCustomerManager = new DAL.CustomerManager();


    public void DeleteCustomer(int customerId) {
        // .. do some logic here ...
        _dalCustomerManager.DeleteCustomer(customerId);
    }
}
```

or is this a better solution because I don't always a instance of the _dalCustomerManger and when I access the dalCustomerManager property it creates a new instance of it when it's null ?

```
public class CustomerManager {

    private DAL.CustomerManager _dalCustomerManager;
    private DAL.CustomerManager dalCustomerManager { 
         get { 
            return _dalCustomerManager ?? (_dalCustomerManager = new DAL.CustomerManager());                
         }
    }


    public void DeleteCustomer(int customerId) {
        // .. do some logic here ...
        dalCustomerManager.DeleteCustomer(customerId);
    }
}
```

Comment: "because I don't always a instance of the _dalCustomerManger" Don´t you? So you set the private field explicitly to null? Otherwise you ALWAYS HAVE an instance to your manager.

Answer (score 1):

This is matter of taste. Unless `DAL.CustomerManager()` has extensive constructor (like allocating lot of classes, doing some time consuming work) it just doesn't matter.

This link you might find useful (about micro optimization in general) : http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater/

Also I'd like to point out that lazy loading of `DAL.CustomerManager` in your code is not thread safe:

```
private DAL.CustomerManager dalCustomerManager { 
  get { 
    // if two threads are calling this you'll allocate two instances.
    return _dalCustomerManager ?? (_dalCustomerManager = new DAL.CustomerManager());                
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your class DAL.CustomerManager is really long-creating, this may help.
In such a situation i prefer Lazy, which can be used like this:

```
public class CustomerManager
{
    private Lazy<DAL.CustomerManager> _lazyDalManager= new Lazy<CustomerManager>(()=>new DAL.CustomerManager());

    protected DAL.CustomerManager DalCustomerManager
    {
        get { return _lazyDalManager.Value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: i want to but I need 15 reputation :(